# How to handle navbar title being pushed to the right?

Tags: react-native, expo

Given the follow situation:

I'm developing an Android/IOS application using react-native with Expo framework, I have 3 screens, Main, Login and Register, to access Login or Register, I need to navigate from Main to either Login or Register.

It's working well, no problem with it, but as you know, when you navigate to any screen you can "go back" using the arrow that appears in the top left of the screen.

In my scenario I have that arrow but I also have an **title** in the navbar of all screens, and when I navigate to Login or Register, the title is pushed to the right.

I did an workaround to it but, I really don't know if it's the right way to handle it, can someone help me?

Workaround used: `headerRight: (<View />)`

Follow the images with the behavior of the title:

[Without the workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKbs9.jpg)

[With the workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONgno.jpg)

[Workaround applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGUE9.png)

**Obs: This workaround need to be applied in each screen, if I apply it in a "general" way to modify all screens, titles without back arrow will be "pushed" to the left, and then I need to do other workaround.**

Thanks!

Comment: @c0der actually I never got a valid answer for this and never found a solution also...

Answer (score 0):

The normal solution is to use this object on each screen

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: <LogoTitle />,
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
        title="Info"
        color="#fff"
      />
    ),
  };
```

check more about it here : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons.html